# Read and filter data from the local storage

Tags: next.js

I have array of phrases that I keep in local storage. When the page loads, I filter this array.

The problem is, I'm getting `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` when I reload the page, I was trying to solve the issue by adding `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` condition, but If I add such condition I get `Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')` error from one of my components where I filter this array.

This is how I get data from local storage:

```
    const getPhraseArr = () => {
    const arr_of_phrases = localStorage.getItem('arr_of_phrases')
    if (arr_of_phrases) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr_of_phrases'))
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }

  const [phraseArr, setPhraseArr] = useState(
    typeof window !== 'undefined' ? getPhraseArr : null,
  )
```

This is how I filter data from the array:

```
  const { phraseApp } = useContext(AppContext)

  const scoreArr = phraseArr.filter(
    (i) => i.substring(0, i.indexOf('_')) == collection.id,
  )
  const colScore = scoreArr.length
```

I am not sure how to avoid such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `useEffect` React hook to accomplish what you want. `useEffect` will only be triggered on the client side (where localStorage can be used).

The code could look similar to this:

```js
const [phraseArr, setPhraseArr] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   const phrases = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr_of_phrases") || "[]");
   setPhraseArr(phrases);
}, []);
```

Comment: With this changes I'm getting another error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')`

Comment: Yes because at first (just before the `useEffect`) your state is `undefined`. You can either initialize your state with an empty array: `useState([])` and/or filter only if `phaseArr` is not undefined: `phraseArr?.filter`

Comment: Yep, thanks! It solved the issue, but now, I have a small lag, I mean, when the list of phrases loads only in 2 sec it starts filtering. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You're welcome. Does it start filtering after 2 sec or does it take 2 sec to filter? If it is option 2, it may be that there is a lot of data or that the filtering function is not optimized. If it's the first then maybe `useMemo` should be used to start the search as soon as the data retrieved from `localStorage` is saved in state: `const colScore = useMemo(() => {const scoreArr = /* filtering function here */; return scoreArr.length}, [phraseArr])`